# Hook all http requests

Tags: hooks, request-filter

How do I hook all http requests in wordpress? More specifically I am interested in examining an http header in the request and then potentially modifying headers in the request so that other plugins that rely on certain headers can work properly.

Many answers discuss hooking responses, but I need to hook the request, not the response.

Comment: Did you find out any solution?

Comment: Not yet but I found some work-arounds